# Closing nested CjuiDialog popup - Yii Framework

Tags: yii

I am trying to develop the screen with nested popup (Popup inside another popup), Now am facing issues to close the inner popup and make visible the outer popup without redirecting to any page. how to achieve this ?

[image]

First popup has one grid and one new button, clicking on new button opens one more popup , here am uploading files and storing the details in DB while submitting the upload button, it should close the inner popup and focus should be in outer popup with updated grid details.
Please give any idea to achieve this ?

My 2nd Popup View Code,

```
<?php
echo CHtml::form('','post',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
    echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'name');
    echo CHtml::button( 'Submit',array('submit' => array('baseContact/SaveAttachDocuments')));  

    echo CHtml::endForm();?>
```

Controller Action for 2nd Popup,

```
public function actionSaveAttachDocuments()
{
    $model=new DocumentAttachmentModel();
    $filename =CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'name');
    $model->type =pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $model->name =pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $model->save();
    /** Here i have to close the 2nd popup and update the grid in 1st popup **/          
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far (in code)?

Comment: @veelen Update code in post

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should close the inner popup by javascript (after client side validation), and then call the controller action for the outer popup again from the `actionSaveAttachDocuments()` method.